Segregated method for numerical solution of a PDE system
I am interested in solving coupled partial differential equations and came across segregated method for the solution where one pde is solved and it's solution used as input for the next pde. This process is repeated until convergence. One description of the method I have found is at https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/segregated-method-for-numerical-solution-of-a-pde-system.645539/.
I am interested in learning more about the segregated approach but my literature search has not been very fruitful. Although I have found works that use the method, those works don't discuss the method in detail for reproducibility of the results. At a minimum, I am interested to learn about (1) speed of convergence, (2) error approximation, (3) memory usage, and (4) general accuracy (say over more complex coupled methods).
